# What is the difference of Stream and MemoryStream

Tags: c#

What is the main difference between `Stream` and `MemoryStream` in C#?

If I need to create a `Stream` without a file shall I use a `MemoryStream` instead?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`MemoryStream` derives from the general class `Stream`.

About `Stream` from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx):

> Provides a generic view of a sequence of bytes. This is an abstract class.

So you can't create an instance of `Stream`. You have to use one of the derived classes, like [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx), etc.

Answer (score 23):

`MemoryStream` and `FileStream` are examples of classes in the .NET framework that inherit from the abstract base class `Stream`, as represented by this condensed inheritance tree:

- System.Object

  - System.MarshalByRefObject

    - **System.IO.Stream**

      - **System.IO.FileStream**
      - **System.IO.MemoryStream**
      - ... several others ...

You would use the `FileStream` to read/write a file but a `MemoryStream` to read/write in-memory data, such as a byte array decoded from a string.

You would not use a `Stream` in and of itself, but rather use it for polymorphism, i.e. passing it to methods that can accept any implementation of `Stream` as an argument.

Comment: What memory is being used for MemoryStream? is it stack

Comment: It must be heap memory, as far as I can imagine.